# Advice for PCB layout 230V AC to 18V DC with another function (beginner continued)

Tags: power, pcb, ac, relay, dc

I am continuing a thread [Beginner's second PCB circuit design: AC to DC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/422114/beginners-second-pcb-circuit-design-ac-to-dc?noredirect=1#comment1048108_422114)

Does this PCB design look better than the previous and do you understand it?

I also want to know if the terminal blocks are placed in the correct direction. How should one layout the components such as op amp etc?

The relay is a acts as a switch for a 230V heater which is also connected to the mains 230V.[image]

[image]

Comment: It is almost impossible to read your schematic. Consider using correct symbols instead of boxes with pins. There should be values on the capacitors instead of part numbers. A neat schematic makes it much easier to understand the circuit. If this is a single layer board, I would put a 100nF cap near the supply pin of the op-amp as decoupling. The PCB layout is improved. Good primary-secondary isolation. Consider routing with 45 degree bends. Any angel routing becomes a mess if you are routing big boards.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will bear that in mind next time. I thought I did add a 100nF for decoupling. 45 degree bends, such as the traces N2 and N3?

Comment: @M2T156 Yes. Eight-directional routing makes things generally easier to follow, though there is no requirement to use it. Seconding Peter's comment about using proper schematic symbols; I can't follow what your schematic is.